# How can I link directly to colorbox from an external link?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have built a portfolio webpage that uses colorbox to display images. I want to be able to link directly to the colorbox on that page from an external link sent to people.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that each image link has a unique id, e.g. <a id="photo1" href="photo1.jpg">

Add something like this to your document ready function, after the colorbox init code:

```
if (location.hash) {
    var link = $(location.hash); // location.hash includes "#" in front
    // change the hasClass() test below to match your image links only
    if (link.length > 0 && link.hasClass('colorbox')) {
        link.click(); // trigger colorbox
    }
}
```

Then send links with the id appended to the URL, e.g. http://example.com/#photo1

Comment: This (veryclever) hack works because the URL anchor hash is also the id selector in jquery.
But note that if the id of the image is its filename, you will most probably have to escape the dot in it, because it is a selector in jquery:
```javascript
var link = $(location.hash.replace(".","\\."));
```